# Unexpected "Identifier" in class body

Tags: godot

I am getting this error
code:

```
extends Timer

onready var water_timer = $WaterTimer

func _ready(): water_timer.start()

func _on_Watertimeout(): if water_level < 50: print("Water the plant!")

func _on_water_timer_timeout():
    pass # Replace with function body.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NcH8.png)

I am trying to make a game where we take care of a plant and this is one of the scripts, all of them have this error

Comment: Did you mean `@onready…` instead of `onready…`